# C++ Correct Usage of LPDWORD

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an array of hWnds of buttons that I want to monitor for clicks. I also have an array of HWINEVENTHOOKs that I will use to monitor them. GetWindowThreadProcessID gives me an LPDWORD process ID, which is not accepted by SetWinEventHook. I am unclear on whether I am correctly using LPDWORDs in this example. Please could somebody point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Thank you to everyone who contributed, I have posted the corrected code below.

New Code:

```
int i = 0;
for (HWND hWnd : hWnds) {
    DWORD processID = 0;
    DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processID);
    hooks[i] = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, 
    NULL,
        WinEventProcCallback, processID, threadID, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
        i++;
}
```

Comment: `DWORD processID = 0;` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processID);` and `SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, 
NULL,
        WinEventProcCallback, processID, threadID, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);` What's the problem??

Comment: It is just bad code and will crash when you try to run it.  You must use `DWORD processID` and pass `&processID` for the second argument.  In other words, you are passing a DWORD by reference so the winapi function can update your variable.  System Hungarian to the rescue, hehe.

Comment: @HansPassant that is not a reference that is the address of (ie a pointer to)

Comment: @WilliamJones: Hans was explaining, how the by-reference idiom is implemented in C (by taking the address of a variable). This was in reference to the sentence preceding that remark.

Comment: @jPadley : is threre a way to get name of button clicked etc when using EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LPDWORD` is just a typedef for `DWORD*` and when a Windows SDK function parameter is a "LPsomething" you generally need to pass a pointer to a "something" (except for the LP[C][W]STR string types).

```
DWORD processID;
DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processID);
if (threadID)
{
  // Do something with threadID and/or processID
}
```

The Windows SDK uses [Systems Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for the Desktop/Classic API.

Comment: The Windows SDK *sometimes* uses Systems Hungarian notation, not always. As an example, the `cch` and `cb` prefixes are clearly Apps Hungarian notation. And most of the COM interfaces use Apps Hungarian notation throughout. Besides, the `LP[C][W|A|T]STR` types *do* point to "something", namely a zero-terminated array of characters.

Comment: I never said the string types don't point to anything but in the context of this question it would be `LPTSTR*` if the string is allocated/set by the called function.

Comment: In that case you should either expand on this, or scrap that remark entirely. As it stands it leaves too much room for interpretation.